# Haskell operator declaration

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to learn haskell from a book with exercises. I can't get through this one and I don't know what's the problem. So I to declare a << definition. In the case of 'a' has less divisors than proper divisors 'b' have, it should be true. Like 6 << 10, 6 have 4 divisors and 10 has 2 proper divisor so it should be False. I have made a definition for divisors and proper divisors, but when I'm trying to use them it just won't happen.

```
    divisors :: Integer -> [Integer]
    divisors a = [n | n <- [1..a], a `mod` n == 0]

    properDivisors :: Integer -> [Integer]
    properDivisors a = [n | n <- [2..a `div` 2], a `mod` n == 0]

    (<<) :: Num a => a -> a -> Bool
    x << y = divisors x < properDivisors y
```

The `(<<) :: Num a => a -> a -> Bool` is fixed.

Comment: Are you getting an error message or something?

Comment: Can you try to give this question a title that will indicate what the operator is actually supposed to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `<<` operator would instead need the type `Integral a => a -> a -> Bool`, since both `div` and `mod` requires `Integral`, not just `Num`.  If you can't use the `Integral` constraint then you'll have to write your own versions of `div` and `mod` that work with all `Num`s.

This can be seen if you comment out all your type signatures:

```
> :set +m
> let divisors a = [n | n <- [1..a], a `mod` n == 0]
|     properDivisors a = [n | n <- [2..a `div` 2], a `mod` n == 0]
|     x << y = divisors x < properDivisors y
divisors :: Integral t => t -> [t]
properDivisors :: Integral t => t -> [t]
(<<) :: Integral t => t -> t -> Bool
```

If we inspect the types of the functions used inside `divisors` and `properDivisors` we get

```
> :t mod
mod :: Integral a => a -> a -> a
> :t div
div :: Integral a => a -> a -> a
> :t (==)
(==) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool
> :i Integral
class (Real a, Enum a) => Integral a where
    ...
> :i Real
class (Num a, Ord a) => Real a where
    ...
> :i Ord
class Eq a => Ord a where
    ...
```

(the other constraints have no preconditions) so in order to use `mod` and `div` the type has to be `Num`, `Eq`, `Ord`, `Enum`, `Real`, and `Integral`, as this is the typeclass hierarchy set up in Haskell.  The two built-in types that fit these constraints are `Int` and `Integer`.  Since `Float` and `Double` do not implement `Integral`, but they do implement `Num`, there's no way you can use `mod` or `div` with just the `Num` constraint.

Comment: Yes, I get that, the problem is that the task is to write the << operator as (<<) :: Num a => a -> a -> Bool. The divisors and properDivisors are my creations trying to solve the task.

It seemed the easiest way of solving this but might be wrong.

Comment: Like I said, you can't use the built-in `div` and `mod` for this if you expect to only have the `Num` constraint.  You'll have to write your own `div` and `mod` for this purpose.  It'll be tough to do, since `Num` does not require `Ord`, and my first thought for implementing them would be to use subtraction and comparisons to approximate these functions, or to use `signum`/`abs` tricks since that would probably require at least `Eq`.

Comment: Also be warned that `divisors x < properDivisors y` is probably not what you're wanting, but rather `length (divisors x) < length (properDivisors y)`.  Using `<` with lists will just do an element-wise comparison until one list runs out of elements.

Comment: I cannot see how making it work with just `Num` is possible at all - `Num` has *no* methods for doing anything other than constructing new numbers. Maybe if the book is so old that it assumes `Num` is still a subclass of `Eq` and `Show`, you could do it in such a way that it works if the type is actually `Integer`, but it would still be meaningless for many `Num`s.